# Contrapositive Proof: Specific Question! Need help!

Tags: real-analysis, discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

I've been stuck on this question for a few days, please help me with this contra positive proof!

> Suppose that $x$ and $y$ satisfy $\frac 1 2 x + \frac 1 3 y = 1$.
>
> Prove that $x^2 + y^2 > 1$.

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Welcome! Please [edit] your question to include your thoughts and efforts on this question, explaining what's giving you trouble. Can you form the contrapositive of this statement? (Although, I doubt that's the easiest way to prove this.)

Comment: The book "hinted" me to use the contrapositive which is x^2 + y^2 < 1 then (1/2)x + (1/3)y does not equal 1.... I would welcome any way to solve. The book we use is very old and contains little information. I had little idea of where to start

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The contrapositive is that

> If $x^2 + y^2 \le 1$, then $\frac 1 2 x + \frac 1 3 y \ne 1$.

Now if $x^2 + y^2 \le 1$, then $-1 \le x, y \le 1$ (why?). How big can $\frac 1 2 x + \frac 1 3 y$ be, then?

Comment: - 1/2 to 1/2 for x and -1/3 to 1/3 for y? So -5/6 to 5/6 ?

Comment: @Cindy Exactly.

Comment: oops I realized that I almost answered my own question sorry thanks

Answer (score 6):

So we know that $$y=3-\tfrac{3}{2}x.$$  Hence
\begin{align*}
x^2+y^2 &= x^2+(3-\tfrac{3}{2}x)^2 \\
        &= \tfrac{13}{4}x^2-9x+9
\end{align*}
which has the minimum $\frac{36}{13}>1$.

Comment: wouldn't the initial line actually be y= 3-3/2 x ?

Comment: Sorry, there was an arithmetic bug.  It should be okay now.

Comment: How did you find the minimum?

Comment: Mathematically, I would differentiate and equate to $0$ to find the $x$-value, then substitute the $x$-value into the polynomial to find the minimum.  In practice, however, I just asked Wolfram|Alpha.

Comment: For a purely algebraic way of finding the minimum, one could also just complete the square.